# How to end a view controller totally?

Tags: viewcontroller

So here is the issue. When I start an application, I start retrieving data from my server.
I have a delegate method with locationManager which detects a change in GPS location.

```
-(void) latLocation:(double)lat lonLocation:(double)lon{
    //Codes to retrieve data from server.

    NSLog(@"Retrieving...");
}
```

The following methods will run the moment a location is updated.
The issue here is, I have used this method in my launch screen which is only supposed to run ONCE. I have used:

```
[self.navigationController popViewController];
```

after finishing my data retrieval.

But it appears my view is still running as the method keeps on calling over and over as my `NSLog` constantly prints over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it by simply niling the delegate.

```
locationManager.delegate = nil;
```